# force close error on emulator but not on device

Tags: android

I was changing the layout of my application.

I'm running it on my device all along, it is working perfectly fine.
However, when I try to run on emulator,
I crashes(give me force close).
I wonder why is this so.

I've gotten the error from logcat

```
   01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.homeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.fuellogproject.homeActivity.onCreate(homeActivity.java:20)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 11 more
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 23 more
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
01-26 06:20:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 26 more
```

homescreen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/background"
   >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogIn"
         style="@style/CustomStyleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Enter" 
                  android:onClick="LogIn"
                  android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAbout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
        style="@style/CustomStyleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="About" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you please post the code at line 20 in your homeActivity ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

Comment: please post your homescreen layout

Comment: @Amrola I've posted it. it work in my phone, but not on emulator

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your layout , please tell me what is the ram size of your emulator ? you can find it here C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini
hw.ramSize

Comment: hw.ramSize=600, I tried to change the ram size, but I still have problem with it

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Give your emulator more RAM. Also be aware that versions of android offers different heap size to the apps, so if you are using different android version on your emulator than on the device it may also be your code fault.

Answer (score 1):

kindly change the hw.ramSize to hw.ramSize=1024MB and do the following :

hw.lcd.density=160

sdcard.size=300M

skin.path=1280x800

skin.name=1280x800

hw.cpu.arch=arm

abi.type=armeabi-v7a

hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8

vm.heapSize=128

hw.ramSize=1024MB

image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\

Hope that helps .

Comment: after I change, I receive this error

[2014-01-26 15:53:25 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2014-01-26 15:53:25 - Emulator] 
[2014-01-26 15:53:25 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2014-01-26 15:53:25 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Can I have a smaller screen?
Like nexus S defaul

Comment: it worked ? yes i will tell you how to get a smaller screen ? 
put is it a correct answer ?

Comment: what is the specs of your PC ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46103/discussion-between-amrola-and-chloe)